# getting error in logout using timer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

whenever I am clicking the logout button it is going to the logout page but Timer1_Tick function is not working and the execution is being stopped in the logout page.It is not going to GuestUser_HOME.aspx page.
The code in the logout page is here.

```
    public partial class WebForm24 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?
        ReturnUrl=index2.html"; 
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session["email"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("GuestUser_HOME.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Logout button click handler and how that is related to this `Timer1_Tick` handler?

Comment: What does a Timer Control have to do with the logout process?

Comment: Post the code of Log out button also , what is the purpose of timer here for logout ??

Comment: without using this timer how can i logout

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your timer had started !? 
check ***IsEnabled*** property before runtime to find out it`s enable or not.

but a better solution is like below ,

***first :***
Create a function for implement sign out operation.

***second :***
use this function in right place , for example in `Click Event` of button or `Page Load` event of sign out page.

***third :***
if you want implement this operation in a `TimerTickEvent` , you must stop timer after complete log out operation , and check if user logged in run SignOut operation not e